# if statement invalid syntax

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute the following code, but I'm getting

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

at the if statement. I'm sure it's related to html as it worked previously without the preceding html; I'm having some difficulty understanding how to go in and out with html and Python as you can see.

```
    class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
                def get(self):
#preceding ("""<html><head> tags...                    
</head>
<body>""")
        self.response.out.write(today.strftime("""<html><body><p style='color:#3E3535'>%A, %d %B</p>""")

        if mon <= 3:
            var1 = "winter"
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions; the if/elifs are indented properly on page.

Comment: The code you've got there is perfectly valid…

Comment: What's this about HTML?  You can't have HTML tags in Python code.

Comment: Are you sure the line above your if statement is valid?

Comment: You'd have to show some more of the code, since what you've got there (sans comment) is perfectly valid.  Also, in your editor, check to see if you're consistently nesting blocks of code - either 4 spaces or a tab, but be consistent.  (You should be able to turn on non-printing characters.)

Comment: Sorry about the semantics...referring to HTML like  self.response.out.write("""<html><body>""")

Comment: Is your comment line actually on two lines?

Comment: Can I request you amend your question with the full traceback?

Comment: @ Jon, comment is just for this post, not in script. I don't get a traceback, just blank page. Syntax error shows in terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your code, then you're missing a close-paren to close out your last function call.

Change it to the following:

```
self.response.out.write(today.strftime("""<html><body><p style='color:#3E3535'>%A, %d %B</p>"""))
```

Comment: thanks, that was it. Going in/out of the html is posing a challenge for me.

Comment: What is the protocol of Stackoverflow as far as a poster receiving negative feedback to a question AFTER the poster has chosen an answer? Thanks in advance, I'm new.

Comment: "Negative" as in "downvoted", or "negative" as in "negative comment"?  For the former I'd look at [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/175248), and the latter - if it happens, flag the comment as offensive.